# Find and return the most recent record by max date and specific ID

Tags: sql, ssms

What I am trying to do list the most recent event type '1081'

But I am only getting a '1081' if its the most recent event type.

The other event type is '1009'

If 1009 is the most recent event type then the record does not appear at all.

If I search all event types then the number of records returned is correct.

I have manually checked through the records and each has an event type 1081 attached to it.

(The event type is matched to a comment that I want to display and I only want to display the most recent 1081 comment)

This is the code

```
SELECT
   o.SiteIdAndName,
   o.Id,
   r.callid,
   o.masterSymptom,
   o.subSymptom,
   o.received,
   o.closed,
   r.eventtype,
   r.datetime,
   r.loggedby,
   r.eventcomments,
   --o.lastedt,
   DATEDIFF(HOUR, received, COALESCE(closed, GETDATE())) AS 'HoursOpen'

FROM
   vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed2016 o
   LEFT JOIN dbo.tblcallev r ON r.callid = o.id --and r.eventtype = 1081

WHERE
   o.SchemeName = 'INDIS'
   AND o.SubSymptom = 'Care' 
   AND Closed is NULL
   AND r.datetime = (
   SELECT MAX(datetime)
   FROM dbo.tblcallevents
   WHERE NOT r.eventtype = 1009
   AND callid = r.callid
   )

Order by 
  r.eventtype
```

Can you help me at all?

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN executes as a regular INNER JOIN since you have that right side table (r) conditions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be very straight foreword query, like below

```
SELECT TOP(1) *--column list here
FROM
vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed2016 o
INNER JOIN dbo.tblcallev r ON r.callid = o.id and r.eventtype = 1081
WHERE o.SchemeName = 'INDIS' AND o.SubSymptom = 'Care' AND Closed is NULL
ORDER BY r.datetime
```

Here `ORDER BY r.datetime` will sort data according to recent datetime values for `r.eventtype = 1081`

**UPDATED :**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.id ORDER BY r.datetime) RN  
       FROM
       vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed2016 o
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblcallev r ON r.callid = o.id and r.eventtype = 1081
       WHERE o.SchemeName = 'INDIS' AND o.SubSymptom = 'Care' AND Closed is NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Hi JaydipJ, thank you for the reply. Your code returns every 1081 event rather than just the most recent. (although I am schooled by how simple you got it :) )

Comment: @Michael if you looking for only top most record then you just need to add `TOP (1)` in your query, this will give only one result for most resent date. Updated Ans

Comment: In total I have 20(dynamic number) separate records and I need the most recent record of each. `TOP (1)` only returns the most recent single record.

Comment: If I understood correctly then you mean to 20 different eventtype expect 1009

Comment: Each record has an individual ID and each ID has several 1081 and 1009 event types attached to it. Each event type is date stamped. I want the most recent 1081 event from each individual ID